# Play sound at certain playProgress or videoTime with greensock?

Tags: actionscript-3, gsap

I'm using greensock LoaderMax to load video files and sound files.  I've copied as much code as is available to me.  A video (s9) is playing and at a certain percentage through the video, I need to play another sound.

```
if(s9.playProgress > .1) // This is what I can't get to work
{
    s12_sound.playSound(); //This sound won't play at .1 playProgress
}

s9.content.visible = true;

s9.playVideo();

stop();

s9.addEventListener(VideoLoader.VIDEO_COMPLETE, play_s9_loop); //This plays a video once s9 is done.

function play_s9_loop(event:Event):void
{
    s9.content.visible = false;
    s9_loop.content.visible = true;
    s9_loop.playVideo();
}
```

I'm guessing you just can't do an if() on playProgress?  Furthermore, I suck at AS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just listen for the INIT event on the video (which typically means it has loaded enough to determine the duration of the video) and then add an AS cue point.

```
//...after you create your VideoLoader...
myVideoLoader.addEventListener(LoaderEvent.INIT, initHandler);
myVideoLoader.load();
function initHandler(event:LoaderEvent):void {
    myVideoLoader.addASCuePoint( myVideoLoader.duration * 0.1, "myLabel" );
    myVideoLoader.addEventListener(VideoLoader.VIDEO_CUE_POINT, cuePointHandler);
}
function cuePointHandler(event:LoaderEvent):void {
    trace("Hit the cue point " + event.data.name);
    s12_sound.playSound();
}
```

Also make sure that you preload that s12_sound so that it's ready to play when you need it. Otherwise, you can call playSound() all you want and it ain't gonna happen :)

Comment: Okay, I tried this, and it traces "Hit the cue point myLabel", but it won't play the sound.  I made sure the function is after my loading queue, and that the INIT listener was before.  I'm guessing there's something else I'm doing that's preventing the sound from playing, but it could be a billion things, the project code is scattered around tons of frames.  I'll repost here if I find the problem.

Comment: WHATTTTTTTT, okay when I published this AND put this online, it worked for some reason and played the sound.  No idea what did that, but it works now.  Thanks so much for your help.  Again, I'm playing with this for the next few days and if I figure out what's going wrong with mine I'll post.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this class before but after reading the docs it looks like you can do something like this:
http://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/loading/VideoLoader.html

```
var mid:Number = s9_loop.duration/2; //get the midpoint using the duration property
s9_loop.addASCuePoint(mid, "middle") //using addASCubePoint to add a cuepoint to the midpoint of the video
s9_loop.addEventListener(VideoLoader.VIDEO_CUE_POINT, handleMidpoint); //listen for the cuepoint
```

Inside the handler function

```
protected function handleMidpoint(e:Event):void{
     //play your sound
}
```

Comment: No dice, didn't play the sound.  To make it simpler, I know the time I need it to play at, and I couldn't get it working, but how would I write a timer that executes on entering the frame and then plays the sound after 59 seconds? I tried a similar timer but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: A timer is not going to give you the accuracy you need, I wouldn't go down that road. Do you know if the VIDEO_CUE_POINT listener is firing? I would look for some examples that use that

Comment: Try taking a look at this as well: http://actionscriptexamples.com/2008/03/13/dynamically-adding-cue-points-to-an-flv-using-the-flvplayback-control-in-actionscript-30/ -are you adding the cue point after the video is loaded?

Comment: What would I trace to see if that's firing?  (Sorry, still a noob)

Comment: And, there is one frame and on that frame is a movieclip called "rewinder" (we made the name awhile back, isn't really a rewinder anymore).  Inside that movie clip is about 20 frames, each with a stop() and an f4v is played on each frame (previously loaded by a queue).  I've got your code on the frame (18) in which the video plays and I need a completely separate mp3 to play at X seconds in.  (Sorry for the complication, trying to give you more detail)

Comment: Post some more code to give me a better idea of what you're talking about

Comment: I tried the comment above this from Jack, and it was working, but not playing the sound for some reason.  The project is scattered around a whole bunch of frames, I'm going to play around with it and if I find the problem I'll repost here.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I appreciate it greatly, and it probably worked - I'm just a moron at AS3 and might have done something wrong.  Sorry for the confusion, I appreciate your help and I'll let you know if I figure out what the problem is. When I published it online it seemed to work (the Jack guy's code).  Again, sorry I don't mean to be a dick, I appreciate the help a lot.